# Can the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{n(n+1)}}$ be explicitly evaluated?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Can the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{n(n+1)}}$ be explicitly evaluated? Here $a>1$.
It is clear that the sum converges by Root Test.
But how to calculate the value of the sum?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: Anything simpler than that?

Comment: None (except some [explicit values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Explicit_values) maybe). If it were...